# my subaru's getting no injection signal from ecu

Tags: starting, subaru, electronic-control-module

I have a problem starting my Subaru engine ej25. I had my sub wire (hot) hit the body of my car and I think I have spiked my ecu (Motec-m400) and nows its doing all sorts of stuff with my coil packs. 2 would glow hot while the other 2 stays frozen cold, while it keep taking others I swap out and now I been through a few and I'm getting frustrated plz I need help??

Comment: Welcome to the site. For reference, what is the year and model of your Subie?

Comment: Sounds like the ECM is fried if it's keeping two coils grounded. You could check for a short to ground on the affected coils. If you have a cam and crank signal at the ECM but no injector pulse at the injectors check for injector pulse at the ECM and check your wiring. Make sure the injectors are getting power.